# Split string in ruby based on whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

suppose I have a string name 
str="I am a sudent of xyz University" 
and i have to split it based on space and store it into new array like 
mystr=["I","am","a","student","of","xyz","university"]
how to do that in ruby?

Comment: Logic is not clear. Describe how you get those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby this would simply be [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split):

```
2.2.3 :001 > str = 'I am a student of xyz University'
  => "I am a student of xyz University" 
2.2.3 :002 > str.split
  => ["I", "am", "a", "student", "of", "xyz", "University"]
```

Comment: Your input string is not what the OP has. And your output is not what the OP wants.